# I want install phpexcel laravel but phpexcel is abandoned

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

I want to install `phpoffice/phpexcel` in My Project.

When `composer install` or `composer update`, i receive error:

> Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
>   Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

What is wrong with my project? Please help me. My project use PHP version 7.1.3 and Laravel version 5.7

Comment: It tells you the issue. Use the maintained php excel package

Comment: What if i want to install phpexcel? Because code i wrote for phpexcel not work in phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Comment: Uhh ok... Well just use phpexcel then?

Comment: Take the time to make the changes so your code will work with PHPSpreadSheet. You will be glad you did. Though you may be able to get PHPExcel to work now it will likely start throwing more errors as you start using current levels of PHP (7.1 is already very out of date and goes out of service before the end of the year).

Answer (score 0):

It means the project is not being maintained. you can still use if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

That message you are getting is just a warning, not an error so there is nothing wrong with your project. So you **could** ignore the warning and continue using the package with your current code.

However, as the message said you **should** avoid using it because the package might stop working properly if you decide to update laravel, php or any other dependencies. And if it does stop working or you encountered a bug, there will no code maintainer to help you solve your issue.

In your case, phpoffice/phpspreadsheet package actually provide a useful entry in their [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/) to help you migrate to their package, so you should definitely give it a read as there are quite a few breaking changes if you decide to use their package.